# strtolower function in php with windows-1254 charset

Tags: php, string

i have page and it has,

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1254">`

when i try to change string with `strtolower()`. it is not working on "Ç,Ö,Ü,Ğ,Ş".

example,

`$str= "ÇaTPÖ";` 
`$str = strtolower($str);` 
`//$str = "ÇatpÖ";`

also i try to change them with `ereg_replace()`, but not working again.

`$str = ereg_replace("Ç","ç",$str);` 
`$str = ereg_replace("Ö","ö",$str);`

so what's the problem do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `mb_strtolower()`:

```
$str = mb_strtolower($str, 'windows-1254');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php

Comment: I also try that,although my php version is 4.4.9 ,i am getting this error, Fatal error: Call to undefined function: mb_strtolower()

Comment: okay, it seems the Multibyte extension isn't enabled on your server. So you can't use any mb_*-functions...

Answer (score 1):

PHP's built-in string manipulation functions are not multibyte-safe.

Check out the set of [mb_* functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php).

Edit: Also something of note: ereg is deprecated. Use preg instead.